# building test artifact using gradle build for a java project

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am new to gradle build, I am currently working on a migrating maven project to gradle. In maven i can build both src jar and also test jar of the project. How do i do the same thing in gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to build the source jar, you don't have to do anything special

1. Use java plugin : `apply plugin: 'java'`
2. Call the `jar` task which is automatically added by the plugin

To build the test jar you can do something as follows:

Create a jar task that packs all your compiled test classes:

```
task jarTests(type : Jar) {
    from sourceSets.test.output
    archiveName "${baseName}-tests.jar"
}
```

Then, make that new task dependent on the `test` task:

```
jarTests.dependsOn 'test'
```

Actually it can depends on the `compileTestJava` task, but you probably don't want it to succeed if you can compile your test classes but unable pass all test.

Now you can run the new `jarTests` task.

There are maybe shorter ways to do achieve this, which I'm unfamiliar of.